# Reset OS without Reformatting

Tags: memory, lubuntu, 32bit

I'm running 32bit Lubuntu OS and wish to know, due to the fact that I'm selling my computer, if there's a way to reset my O.s. to it's original stats (meaning like it was freshly installed as far as amount of storage space taken) without reformatting & re-installing it?

Comment: You could reinstall that OS from its USB key, or clear the disk using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=64k`; I don't think you can "reset" it

Comment: Short of Ubuntu being an OEM installation and the manufacturer doing something special, there isn't any way short of re-installing it or manually wiping the disk.